# Calling an LWC before update

Tags: lightning-web-components

As the title says, is there a way to call an LWC before/as a record update is made?

The request from the client would be, when they attempt to check a checkbox on the account, a pop-up confirmation screen/component shows with disclaimer text (e.g. lightning-confirm), when they click "confirm" the change is then updated.

The LWC would be empty other than the lightning-confirm logic and would just sit on the page.

Is it possible to call an LWC in this way? Or is there any other way a confirmation could be added to a record change?

My backup solution is to make the field read-only and have a screenflow called from a quick action to update the field.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdin5UAB/warning-messages) that closely matches what you're asking for, but there's no timeline on when or if this feature might be released. In addition to the idea of making the field read-only with a flow, it'd also be possible to write code for a [Standard Action Override](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.standard_actions_overrides.htm&type=5), which would allow you to make a completely custom experience. You could pair this with lightning:recordEditPage/lightning-record-edit-page to minimize the amount of work you'd have to do to replicate the standard layout.